# how to give path of bat file to trigger it as webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, batch-file

while executing a .bat file as standalone, i am able to invoke it but when i expose it as a rest webservice, i get error as - bat file can not be found.

how do i set path for bat file to execute it?

```
@GET
    @Path("/triggerMyBat")
    public Response triggerMyBat() throws Exception {
    //public static void main(String[] args){
        try {

                     String ss = null;

                        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start myBat.bat");
                        BufferedWriter writeer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
                        writeer.write("dir");
                        writeer.flush();
                        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                        while ((ss = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(ss);
                        }
                        while ((ss = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(ss);
                        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity("Success").build();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bat file is located in folder referenced by cmd.exe then you can call it. Otherwise you need to set full path to your file or put bat's folder in Path variable of Environment variable of windows .

Comment: how can i check which path cmd.exe is referring to?

Comment: Thanks, I gave the full path of the bat file and it worked - eg -  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start D:/myBat.bat");